# Изменилось название приложения, нужно ли менять (перерегистрировать) рекламный баннер AdMob?

Tags: android, admob

Незначительно изменилось название приложения (добавилось слово в названии), нужно ли менять (перерегистрировать) рекламный баннер AdMob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не нужно. Приложения идентифицируются по пакету и ключу подписи. В случае AdMob используется только пакет.

Название же берётся из ресурсов и может быть разным на разных локалях/устройствах и менять его можно в любой момент.

Comment: Спасибо, друг! )